# Show there is an oriented atlas.

Tags: differential-geometry, orientation

> Suppose $M$ is a manifold with the following property:
>
> Every point $p \in M$ has a neighborhood $U$ and a continuous ordered
>   frame on $TM\vert_U = TU$ which evaluated at every $q \in U$ forms a
>   positive basis of $T_q M$.
>
> Show that an orientation on each tangent space satisfying the above
>   property determines an oriented atlas on $M$.

**Attempt:**

Well somehow, I will have to produce an atlas of charts such that for any two such charts $\phi, \psi$, we have that $\det (D(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(p))  > 0$.

I'm not sure how I will have to do this.

Given $p \in M$, I know there is a chart $(U, \phi)$ near $p$. I guess I then could look at $T_q U = T_qM$ and see if has the same orientation as the ordered frame. If yes, then we keep the chart. If not, then we change one coordinate with a minus sign. But I'm not sure if this is the right way to proceed.

Comment: You will only get to some open set of $M$. For example, the Moebius strip satisfies the hypotheses, every manifold does, but not the conclusion. The choice of consistent orientation can get you to the strip minus a line across the strip, but once you need to choose the orientation at points on the line you can make it agree with the orientation on one side, but it will disagree with the orientation at the other side of the line.

Comment: @Matematleta That is what they are doing already and it will only give you an atlas on an open subset only, potentially a proper one. You have no way to ensure that you can jump out of the open set. For all you know, the neighborhood that exists at $p$ could be inside $V_i$.

Comment: @Matematleta You are missing what I said above, that all manifolds satisfy the hypotheses of the problem, in particular non-orientable ones like the Moebius strip.

Comment: @Matematleta But note that even ignoring this concrete problem, the technique of advancing to ever larger open sets is useful in other contexts too. So, it is important to understand how it will only gives you a property on an open set and this might not be the entire space. I have in mind analytic continuation, as another example.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Yes, indeed. +1

Comment: No, the Moebius strip does not satisfy the continuity conditions! The frame is continuous. On the Moebius strip, this is not the case?

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Is that not correct?

Comment: The condition only needs to be satisfied on a neighborhood. So, for each point take only a small rectangle around it. You can choose a continuous oriented frame on it without problem.

Comment: So the question I'm trying to prove is incorrect?

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I forgot to include a sentence in the exercise: "Show that an orientation on each tangent space satisfying the above property determines an oriented atlas on M." I'm not sure if this sentence makes a difference?

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Something else must be missing.

Comment: The exercise literally is: (a) Show that a choice of oriented atlas induces an orientation on each tangent space, with this property: for every point $p \in M$ there is a neighborhood $U$ and a continuous ordered frame on $TU$ which evaluated at every $q \in U$ forms a positive basis of $T_qM$. (I managed to prove this), (b) Show the converse: an orientation on each tangent space satisfying the above property determines an oriented atlas on $M$.

Comment: You should reformulate your question: You are given a family of orientations $\omega_q$, $q \in M$, of the tangent spaces $T_q M$. Only this allows you to say that some ordered frame forms a positive basis of $T_q M$. Then show that the family $\omega_q$ determines an oriented atlas on $M$ provided the condition in your question is satisfied. By the way, where does the exercise come from?

Comment: You should also give the definition of "continuous ordered frame". Is it a collection of continuous local sections $s_i : U \to TM$ such that $(s_1(q),\ldots,s_n(q))$ forms an ordered basis of $T_q M$?

Comment: Yes, that's my definition of continuous ordered frame. This was an exercise in my notes from my differential geometry professor, so the exact source I don't know. @PaulFrost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given a family $\omega$ of orientations $\omega_p, p \in M$, of the tangent spaces $T_p M$ such that every point $p \in M$ has a neighborhood $U$ and a continuous ordered frame on $TM\vert_U = TU$ which evaluated at every $q \in U$ forms a positive basis of $T_q M$. Call such $U$ *admissible* and the continuous ordered frame $\sigma$ on $TU$ *positively oriented rel. $\omega$*.

Positive basis of $T_q M$ means that the ordered frame represents the orientation $\omega_p$ (recall that an orientation is an equivalence class of ordered frames = ordered bases).

Now let $\phi : U \to V \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a chart on $M$ such that $U$ is admissible and connected. Note that each $p \in M$ has an open neighborhood $U$ carrying such a chart. We know that $\phi$ induces a bundle isomorphism $T \phi : TU \to TV$. The latter bundle admits a canonical bundle isomorphism $\iota_V : TV \to V \times \mathbb R^n$.

The bundle isomorphism $\tilde T \phi = \iota_V \circ T \phi$ establishes a bijective correspondence between continuous ordered frames on $TU$ and continuous ordered frames on $V \times \mathbb R^n$. The frames on $\mathbb R^n$ can be identfied with matrices in $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ (each vector in a frame is identified with a column in the associated matrix). Thus each continuous ordered frame $\gamma$ on $V \times \mathbb R^n$ can be identified with a continuous map $\gamma^* : V \to GL(n,\mathbb R)$. Since $V$ is connected, $\gamma^*(V)$ is contained either in $GL_+(n,\mathbb R)$ = set of matrices with positive determinant or in $GL_-(n,\mathbb R)$ = set of matrices with negative determinant. Let us say that $\gamma$ is *positively oriented* if $\gamma^*(V) \subset GL_+(n,\mathbb R)$. This means that $\gamma(x)$ represents the standard orientation $o_x$ of $\{x\} \times \mathbb R^n$ for all $x \in V$.

Now let $\mathcal O$ denote the set of all charts $\phi : U \to V$ on $M$ having the following properties:

1. $U$ is connected.
2. For each $q \in U$, the orientation $\omega_q$ of $T_qM$ is mapped by $\tilde T_q \phi$ to the standard orientation $o_{\phi(q)}$ on $\{\phi(q)\} \times \mathbb R^n$.

For each $p \in M$ there exists a chart in $\mathcal O$ such that $p \in U$. To see this, choose any chart $\phi' : U' \to V'$ around $p$. Let $U''$ be an admissible open neigborhood of $p$ and $U \subset U' \cap U''$ be a connected open neigborhood of $p$. Then $\phi'$ restricts to a chart $\phi : U \to V$. Of course $U$ is again admissible. Let $\sigma$ be a positively oriented continuous ordered frame on $TU$ and let $\gamma$ be the continuous ordered frame on $V \times \mathbb R^n$ which corresponds to $\sigma$ under $\tilde T \phi$. If it is positively oriented, we are done. If not, then $\gamma^*(V) \subset GL_-(n,\mathbb R)$. But then then the chart $\psi = R \circ \phi : U  \to R(V)$, where $R$ is a reflection on $\mathbb R^n$, satisfies 1. and 2.

Thus $\mathcal O$ is an atlas on $M$.

We claim that $\mathcal O$ an oriented atlas. So let $\phi_1 : U_1 \to V_1$ and $\phi_2 : U_2 \to V_2$ be charts in $\mathcal O$. Let $\psi = \phi_2 \circ \phi_1^{-1}  : \phi_1(U_1 \cap U_2) \to \phi_2(U_1 \cap U_2)$ be the transition function. On the tangent spaces it satisfies $T_x \psi = T_{\phi_1^{-1}(x)} \phi_2 \circ T_x \phi_1^{-1}$. Via the $\iota_{V_i}$ it corresponds to the "Euclidean" derivative $d \psi(x) : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$. But by construction it is *orientation preserving* which means that the determinant of $d \psi(x)$ is positive.

Comment: So basically for any pair of admissible sets $U$ and $V$, you can choose charts in such a way that the differential of the  transition functions has positive Jacobian and you do this by transferring everything to Euclidean space, where you can always assign a global orientation. But I'm still having a hard time visualizing why this wouldn't also apply to the Mobius band (I can see intuitively why not though!)  Is it just because with the Mobius, it is not possible to choose charts as in your proof, so that you get an atlas? If not, why not?

Comment: @Matematleta A manifold being orientable means that we can make a **consistent** choice of orientations of tangent spaces. What this means is made precise in the question and the answer. Now assume this were possible for the Möbius band $M$. Consider its middle circle $S$. Start with an orientation $\omega_p$ of some $T_pM$ for $p \in S$. Propagate it locally consistent along $S$ until you return to $p$. Then the half-twist has turned $\omega_p$ into $-\omega_p$. Thus there is no orientation on $M$.

Comment: Yes this is how I see it also. So what fails here is the condition of there being a "$continuous$ ordered frame"? I seemed to have a similar kind of confusion when I studied analytic continuation.

Comment: @Matematleta The point is to distinguish between local orientations and global orientations. A local orientation in some open neigborhood $U$ of $p \in M$ can always be found. Just take a chart $\phi : U \to V$ around $p$ and use $\tilde T \phi$ to transfer the standard orientation of $\mathbb R^n$ to orientations on the $T_qM$, $q \in U$. But this local transfer in general does not produce consistent orientations $\omega_p$ of **all** tangent spaces - it is only possible if we have an oriented atlas on $M$. Let us change the viewpoint.

Comment: Given a family of orientations $\omega_p$ of the tangent spaces. When is it a consistent family in the sense that it agrees locally with a family of "chart transferred" orientations? And exactly here the condition in the question enters. It avoids the orientation transfer via charts, but replaces it by the use of  continuous ordered frames which locally induce the given orientations $\omega_p$. Again this is in general impossible globally on $M$.

Comment: I understand the idea, but I think I am lost in a thicket of definitions.  By "a family of orientations $ω_p$" do you mean an equivalence class of frames on $M$? And then if it turns out that for every $p\in M$ there is an open $U\ni p$ such that the frame is continuous as sections of $TU$, and represents $\omega_q$ for $q\in U$ then we say that the orientation is continuous at $p$. I understand that this is a local property. (continued below)

Comment: ....Now I contrast this with the statement "positive basis of $T_qM$ means that the ordered frame represents the orientation $ω_p.$" and the difference seems to arise from the word "ordered". What does it mean for the frame to be ordered and how does this fit into the definition I gave above (if it is even correct.) I also know that orientations can be defined through $n-$ forms so if the explanation is simpler that way, I would be happy to see it.

Comment: @Matematleta An ordered frame is an ordered basis, an orientation is an equivalence class of such (two ordered frames being equivalent if the automorphism mapping one frame to the other has positive determinant). A family of orientations on $M$ is any collection of orientation $\omega_p$ of $T_p M, p \in M$. There are uncountably many such families, most of them will not be continuous at **all** points. An orientation of $M$ is such a special family. Concerning $n$-forms: This is a new question.

Comment: Yes OK, I wanted to be sure because I have seen slightly different definitions of things like orientations and I find it confusing. Now I think I get what you wrote in the comments! There is always a way to put an orientation on $TU$ using the charts, but the problem arises when you have two such $U$ and $V$  and you try to ensure that the transition functions on $U\cap V$ have either $+$ or $-$ det. This is not generally possible but in case we have the hypothesis in the OP's question, it is, and this is just what your proof shows. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! To get an orientation on $TU$ it is equivalent to work with a continuous ordered frame on $U$ or to work with a chart on $U$. The frame approach has the benefit of not using local coordinates

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain this in such detail.